# phantomjs chrontab could not connect to x display

Tags: cron, phantomjs

I am trying to schedule a call to phantomjs using chron. The phantomjs will open a website and save a screenshot, and I do want to set this up routinely. My machine runs headless, no display connected.
I am using a bash script to call phantomjs, e.g.

```
phantomjs snapshot.js website.com snap.png
```

This code is running fine when excecuted on the shell manually.
Now, when I set up a chrontab for it, an error occurs.

> qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
>   Could not connect to any X display.

I can solve this error by changing the code to:

```
DISPLAY=localhost:11.0
phantomjs snapshot.js website.com snap.png
```

This works fine as long as I am logged in over shell and the crontab is running. When I log out, it will give the same error as above.

When I set the display to

```
DISPLAY=:0
```

, as I saw in some solutions for similar problems, it reads

> qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0 Could
>   not connect to any X display.

, both running locally and under crontab.

I set the PATH and the XAUTHORITY='home/usr/.Xauthority' in my shell script.

Many thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer:
Exporting the platform variable to offscreen in the script that calls phantomjs did the job.

```
export DISPLAY=:0    
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM='offscreen'
phantomjs snapshot.js www.website.com website.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @tlhenvironment

The only solution to work for me.

First I downloaded minimalistic 32-bit version of webkit and created softlinks:

```
sudo wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-i686.tar.bz2
sudo tar xvjf phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-i686.tar.bz2 -C /usr/local/share/
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-i686/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/share/phantomjs
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-i686/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-i686/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs
```

And then edited this file:

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/phantomjs
```

And put above lines before execution